# Getting a desktop environment Debian

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

I installed the latest stable release of Debian and I don't like the interface I want it to be similar to the Debian desktop installed by default like the Raspberry Pi has. Is there a way to change this easily I have been searching but cannot find it. I want a start style menu and icons on the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like xfce more than lxde

```
# apt-get install xorg xfce4 xfce4-goodies thunar-archive-plugin synaptic gdebi wicd
```

There are more gui to choose for debian. [Install GUI on debian 7 wheezy](http://namhuy.net/1085/install-gui-on-debian-7-wheezy.html)

Answer (score 0):

The raspberry pi uses LXDE.

Installation instructions for a Debian desktop are located here: https://wiki.debian.org/LXDE